# mysql set rank by rank_pts

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with columns:

```
id name rank rank_pts
1  Nick  0    15
2  N0NE  0    12
3  Non2  0    26
```

How can I set rank by rank_pts ?

Comment: With an `UPDATE` statement. (What have you tried?)

Comment: I need rank in format, 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable.

```
SET @i= 0;
UPDATE your_table SET rank = (@i:=@i+1) ORDER BY rank_pts;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update your_table
join (SELECT @row:= 0) r
set rank = (@row := @row + 1)
order by rank_pts desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13974752/1639910) to not only rank by rank_pts but how to handle the situation of two rank_pts being the same. Replace score with rank_pts