# How do I deal with a tie in MySQL rank column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I would like to rank my entries based on a total score column but I need to have ties if the scores are the same. The query below successfully ranks, but the rank goes up even if there is a tie.

Here is my current query:

```
SET @r=0; UPDATE table SET rank= @r:= (@r+1) WHERE `complete` = 1 ORDER BY score DESC;
```

I have been reading a ton of posts but haven't found an explanation of doing this in an UPDATE.

```
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| id | lName     | score       | rank        |
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | Rosebrock |          50 |           5 |
|  2 | Kolley    |          58 |           3 |
|  3 | Bartley   |          11 |           6 |
|  4 | Bell      |          58 |           4 |
|  5 | Daugherty |          63 |           2 |
| 85 | Harp      |          78 |           1 |
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Can you show us your sample data and table please?

Comment: @bonCodigo, sorry that took so long...I only really use sequel pro. Terminal idiot.

Comment: give some respect to yourself, remove that 'idiot' part ;) in the comment. Now there are good answers here already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table scores (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  score INT NOT NULL,
  rank INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO scores (score) VALUES (1), (20), (10), (25), (10), (20);

SET @rank=0, @score=-100;

UPDATE scores 
SET rank=IF(@score=(@score:=score), @rank, @rank:=@rank+1)
ORDER BY score;
```

Same here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90c3b/2/0

Answer (score 1):

See this question/answer for some ideas on implementing a Dense Ranking in MySQL:

[MySQL equivalent of ORACLES rank()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320173/mysql-equivalent-of-oracles-rank)

Comment: I'll definitely be reading these articles in the near future. Thank you for that!